# Querying an array in a JSON column on MySQL with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
class CabinetList(Resource):
def get(self):
    devices = Device.query.filter(Device.type == 'CABINET').all()
    return {'cabinets':list(x.json() for x in devices)}
```

generating this JSON which is stored in a JSON MySql column:

```
 {
   "cabinets":[
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"Armario 1",
         "online":true,
         "setup":0.0,
         "type":"CABINET",
         "data":{
            "lockers":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "content":"Pala",
                  "enabled":true,
                  "busy":false
               },
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "content":"Azada",
                  "enabled":true,
                  "busy":false
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

With this code I can change the "busy" property of the chosen index

```
def get(self, device_id, locker_id):

    if not 1 <= locker_id <= 32:
        return {'error': 'device not found'}, 404

    device = Device.query.filter(and_(Device.id == device_id, Device.type == 'CABINET')).first()
    if not device:
        return {'error': 'device not found'}, 404

    # Update the current status for the locker
    device.data['lockers'][0]['busy'] = True
    
    return {'cabinet': device.json()}
```

It works, but I don't want to refence the item by its index I want to change the property for the item matching its 'id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are making reference to this line, where you would like to not use `0` as index to access the correct locker:

```
device.data['lockers'][0]['busy'] = True
```

I think the most simple solution would be to filter the locker by provided `locker_id`:

```
for locker in device.data['lockers']:
    if locker['id'] == locker_id:
        locker['busy'] = True
        break
else:
    raise Exception("Locker not found")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, the solution was so simple that I'm a little embarrased I did not find it myself. First python project.